# Equivalent to gpresult for local security policy

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, command-line, powershell, group-policy

I just wonder how I can show the currently applied Security-Policy (not Group-Policy) from a machine from the command-line.

i know i can show the current applied Group-Policy with gpresult using

```
gpresult /r
```

Is there an equivalent for the security-policy? commandline or powershell?
I do not want do use `secpol.msc`, because I need something for the commandline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use [SecEdit.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/secedit-export), or [LGPO.exe](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/) or download an use the PolicyFileEditor module from the MS PowerShellGallery.com

[Manage Local Group Policy Objects from PowerShell and Desired State Configuration](https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/manage-local-group-policy-objects-from-powershell-and-desired-state-configuration/)

```
Find-Module -Name 'PolicyFileEditor' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```